# how to include variable values in parameters in ember brackets?

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember-lazy-load for lazy loading

I have this line

```
 {{lazy-image url="{{url}}{{image.thumbnail_url}}" }}
```

I know I can't include brackets within brackets... but how would I include the var values in the url parameter?

Comment: Use a computed property and pass that property into the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a computed property as blessenm suggested or you could use the [{{concat}}](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_concat) template helper:

```
{{lazy-image url=(concat url image.thumbnail_url) }}
```